# What does the the "System cooling policy" under "Processor power management" on Windows 7 do?

Tags: windows-7, power-management

On Windows 7 you have the ability set the System cooling policy to passive. What does that actually do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

System Cooling Policy lets you change the cooling mode of your system.

> What does this actually do?

**Active increases the fan speed** before slowing the processor to maintain cooling, while **Passive slows down the processor** before increasing the fan speed. Passive saves a lot more power as it reduces the clock on your processor, hence giving your more battery time.

*[Source](http://www.ithinkdiff.com/different-new-power-saving-options-in-windows-7/)*

Comment: But which one is better for the **health** of the computer? (assume battery life is not an issue here)