# Can the Asus Zenbooks be used safely with their lids closed?

Tags: external-display, asus-laptop, ultrabook, zenbook

From all the images of the Zenbooks that I've seen, it would appear closing the lid would obstruct most or all airflow, potentially overheating the machines.

Is this the case? Can they be used with closed lids to allow external monitor use (like a desktop computer)?

Comment: I’m confused. (1) wouldn’t closing the lid make it go into standby? (2) does it really vent the hot air **up** instead of to the side? It [doesn’t look like it](http://images.google.com/images?q=zenbook&safe=off&sout=1). `o.O`

Comment: Many computers will not go to standby if an external monitor, keyboard and mouse are hooked up. Even if it does, I assume standby could be disabled.

Comment: To me, it looks like the air _is_ vented up against the screen, but perhaps there are other openings that I missed. I don't own one of these (yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lack of airflow may cause your computer to run at higher temperature.

Even if this does not exceed the laptop's specifications,
you could still be shortening your battery life.

In addition, as far as I can see, the battery on this model is not easily replaceable
and you’ll probably void your warranty by doing so.

This is taken from the article [How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries) :

[image]

As the laptop will most probably be connected to the mains while its lid is closed,
battery charge will probably remain at 100%, where temperature highs have maximum effect.

Comment: Based on those figures, I'm not surprised my girlfriend's 2009 MacBook Pro can barely last an hour on light load. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: You may be interested in this [other answer](http://superuser.com/a/429165/8672) of mine.

Answer (score 3):

I own an Asus UL30A which I believe is an older model of zen UX{21,31}. For what it's worth I often leave my computer with the lid closed at night... on my bed. I haven't experienced any problems yet. It gets a little warm, perhaps up to 65 degrees according to sensors(1), normally 60 or less I think.

Mind you, I have not tried to let it compile the linux kernel or similar CPU intensive jobs. I think it'll be fine, but YMMV.

Here's the specs for the UL30A (sorry, not the best source): http://www.laptopmag.com/review/laptops/asus-ul30a.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Although it does look quite similar, I'm still hoping to hear from an owner of an UX{21,31} or get a more definitive answer.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks for the feedback and good luck :-)

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning the climate you live in. I couldn't leave my laptop on my bed because **I'd** overheat, let alone the laptop haha

Comment: @Robotnik Yes, that's a good point. I live in Northern Europe, so a fairly cool climate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it with a closed lid with no problems; I use it like this every day. I don't know what type of work you do, but if you're stressing the hardware a lot it's good to lift up the tail of the Zenbook a little bit (about 1 inch/2cm) to create space for airflow. Its not needed, but I think that can extend life of my machine. :)

Comment: Some of the pictures leave room for doubt about some space being left open between the (closed) hinge for at least _some_ airflow. Could you comment on that? Can any air pass through with the lid closed?

Comment: I have not this notebook but I never seem any issue with close my LID so if you do not want to close it completely just close it enough to turn off the monitor(LCD).

Comment: No,if your lid is closed,no air can flow under the lid. Todays notebook have good cooling systems, its not big deal close lid and wokr on it like on desktop.

Comment: Actually I now own one of these, and can report that airflow is not a big issue with the lid closed. The hot air will simply vent out from beneath the LCD hinge instead of above it.

Comment: Old thread but couldn't resist, own this one too,  it gets really hot (running linux).  The airflow is indeed reversed, it 'sucks' on the top, blowing it out on the bottom.   I work with the back lifted on decorative rubber rings originally made to put your pots/pans on.