# How to close the lid on the Asus Zenbook without putting it to sleep?

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, zenbook

I'm using a new Asus Zenbook with Windows 8.1. To avoid problems with the tiny screen, I've bought a docking station and external monitor for the desktop.

Is it safe to close the lid on the laptop while working? How do I change the setting to prevent it from going to sleep when I close the lid?

Comment: You might want to read [Can the Asus Zenbooks be used safely with their lids closed?](http://superuser.com/q/427359) before you decide to do this.

Comment: Under Windows 7, the choice of reaction on closing the lid is possible in the Energy Options. Right-click on the energy/power icon in your task bar and look on the left side of the shown dialog. I would expect that a device can be operated safely with closed lid, if there is a docking station available for it.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible in Windows to disable the 'sleep' action on lid close. However, you may experience some [heat dissipation issues](https://superuser.com/q/427359/107240) due to the placement of the vents on the Asus Zenbook range being under the (now closed) lid. Here's how to do it anyway, but there is another option that I'll list below:

#### 1. Disable Sleep Mode on Lid close

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and in the *'Run...'* box, type `powercfg.cpl` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will open the Power Options:

[image: The Power Options Panel]

Click the *'Choose what closing the lid does'* link from the left side panel, and under the *'When I Close the Lid'*, change the setting to 'Do nothing' when Plugged in.

[image: Changing the action on lid close]

I recommend leaving the 'sleep on battery', as you'll usually want your laptop to conserve power whilst on the move.

#### 2. Turn off the monitor (and leave the lid up)

Usually laptops have a button that disables the output on it's primary monitor, turning it off entirely. I cannot be certain if your Asus Zenbook does, but it's worth looking for as it's handy to have.

If it does not, this can still be done from within Windows. Right-Click your desktop and go to *'Screen Resolution'*

You should see two example displays. Hit 'Identify' to show you which number represents which monitor, and then under 'Multiple Displays', select 'Show Desktop only on Monitor X', where 'X' is the monitor number you wish to use.

[image: Show Desktop only on one monitor]

Click apply, and your laptop's screen will turn off, allowing you to use the other monitor as your primary monitor whilst docked.

#### References

- [The Windows Club: Choosing what closing the lid does](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/choose-what-closing-the-laptop-lid-does)