# Advanced power options - processor power managment

Tags: windows-7, cpu, power-management, speedstep, cool-n-quiet

My cpu has p states at 2.3 ghz, 2.1 ghz, 1.1 ghz, and 800 mhz. In the advanced power options-processor power management. Windows allows you to change the percentage. Does this percentage get "rounded" to the nearest supported pstate?

Edit: When I put in 5%, cpuz shows 800 mhz regardless of load, instead of 115mhz.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What Is Minimum And Maximum Processor State In Windows 7 Power Management?](http://superuser.com/q/323738/108226)

Comment: I think it is, I should research better next time :)