# CPU performance monitoring and diagnosis Maximum Frequency drop

Tags: performance, cpu, battery

Question: what might be the reason why **the maximum frequency goes down** to 49%, while this is not sufficient to run existing processes? (please note if I am wrong in interpreting that CPU usage is calculated as % of the maximum frequency - correct? So the computer is effectively running at 50% of maximum capacity?)

See as well the other graphs per below - my complete freezes of the computer start with the first graph (100 CPU, max freq 49)

**Computer stall**
[image: Computer stall]

After I go to battery and remove the power plug, the CPU usage drops (second graph - to 45 with maximum freq still at 49) and performance comes back.

**Computer coming partially to live when moving to battery**
[image: Computer coming partially to live when moving to battery]

Then finally after a few minutes the maximum frequency goes up to e.g. 80 again (at the moment that i probably no longer need it). Core temperatures stay stable, no hard disk failure found. Any tips welcome (should I manually set the minimum maximum frequency to e.g. 80%)?

**Computer fully recovering**
[image: Computer fully recovering]

System characteristics per below

```
•   OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
•   Version 6.1.7600 Build 7600
•   System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
•   System Model    Latitude E6410
•   System Type x64-based PC
•   Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz, 2400 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
•   BIOS Version/Date   Dell Inc. A09, 26/05/2011
•   SMBIOS Version  2.6
•   Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
•   Total Physical Memory   7.80 GB
•   Available Physical Memory   3.40 GB
•   Total Virtual Memory    15.6 GB
•   Available Virtual Memory    9.69 GB
•   Page File Space 7.80 GB
```

Comment: For some info to assist, look at this thread, http://superuser.com/questions/323738/what-is-minimum-and-maximum-processor-state-in-windows-7-power-management If you could indicate how those items are set now?  Also it is good to tell which OS your using in all situations (or tag for it). We know you have battery, but it still does not hurt to put in the Actual model of the computer.

Comment: I think the exact mechanism might vary with OS and processor - might help to mention the processor, even if the overall question is generic

Comment: Apologies - added informaiton - please let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct 50% max Freq should indicate that the "clocking" on the cpu is half speed.  There is some possibility that the motherboard software of the computer is believing it is too hot, and throttled down the processor. Is there any way you can cool it extra and test that theory?   To test for highest speed, in the power properties set to 100% for the maximum.