# minimum allowable CPU speed

Tags: cpu, power-management, cpu-usage

How can I determine the minimum allowable speed for my CPU to run the computer. Having the option to reduce the CPU to 0 is not logic nor allowable in Win8. Even if you set the Max. processor performance (in advance power option) to 20% windows will not lower your processor to this stage and the CPU will remain produce about 40% of it's speed.

Any idea?

Comment: You have to do this by setting the frequency and power to lower values the the default values

Comment: Not sure if related to your question, but Indrek gives a great answer about CPU power states in Windows here: http://superuser.com/questions/323738/what-is-minimum-and-maximum-processor-state-in-windows-7-power-management