# Clock down Intel i7 3610QM

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, overclocking, underclock

I have some big troubles with my CPU. It is getting too hot and therefore performs a *thermal shutdow* which basically means it just kills itself.

Since I don't need the full power of this CPU I was wondering if I can slow down the CPU speed using a tool.

Does anybody know if that is possible and recommend a tool? I've been looking on the Intel-website but could not found anything ..

Operating System: Windows 7

Thank you!

Comment: You should clean the cooling fins.  (And maybe underclock/undervolt in addition).

Comment: What operating system?  See http://superuser.com/questions/323738/what-is-minimum-and-maximum-processor-state-in-windows-7-power-management

Comment: Try using power saving options.

Comment: Turning down the processing speed is NOT A FIX for this problem.  Clean your exhaust vents, clean your intake vents, clean the fan and ensure it's still working, ensure the heat-pipes, heat-sink and other cooling apparatus pieces are connected properly and not obviously damaged.  If you do/confirm all this and still have overheat problems take it back to the manufacturer, because it's BROKEN.

Comment: @BenVoigt This seems to work. I set it to 50% and I still can play BF3 without having a thermal shutdown!

Answer (score 1):

[Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) (click 'More Downloads', the big download link seems to be spyware) has an 'overheat protection' mode that informs you when your CPU heat gets to a certain level, and has the options of running a certain program at that time or offer a shutdown. At the very least you can use it to inform yourself of impending shutdowns so you can save your data.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be in your BIOS where you will need to make the changes. Ever BIOS is a little different so you'll need to look up your specific BIOS settings.

**And as Ben noted those setting might not be there.

***One more edit! you could get a cooling pad [Cooling Pad Conv at Tom's](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/343671-28-3610qm-heat-questions)

Happy Hunting!

Comment: Most laptop BIOSes (3610QM is a laptop processor) are missing 90% of the usual BIOS settings, including these.

Comment: LOL Now that's a great point Ben! Didn't notice it was a Laptop.

Comment: On the plus side, laptop CPUs have very aggressive power-saving capabilities built in.  Simply reducing the highest P-State should have the desired effect, and this can be done in software.  OP didn't provide any information about his OS, however.

Answer (score 0):

try : SMBCFG just gooogle it probably u will need the latest version for your laptop.

Edit: you need a bos boodable media, its used to acces dmi/bios externaly... mainly for writing tattoo

**BE CAREFULL**

This tool is basically made for DMI adjustments for tattooing mainboards after being replaced.

Messing up DMI settings can make it impossible to activate your windows, it might give some un explainable blue screens or even an non booting system. (an copy of original dmi can be put back with a lot of trouble or by bringing it to the service center where the original warranty came from.

u will need a dos bootable media, with the smbcfg module stored on that media.

With this tool u can arrange all bios settings (also the hidden ones) and also most of the text found in bios can be altered.

Suggestion: only change frequenty (or multiplier probably that cpu is engineer unlocked)

mostly you can also adjust threads/HT (seperetly without switching full multi thread/core functionality off