# How to control cpu speed through windows?

Tags: windows, cpu

Linux has some awesome apps, one of them is the app which allows you to control speed (MHz) at which your CPU is able to operate.

Is there something similar for windows 8.1?

Comment: You mean [like this](http://superuser.com/q/323738/167187)?

Comment: @Vinayak simillar, but maybe there is some sort of application which would allow me to control CPU speed easier (faster)?

Comment: I don't know of a universal application that supports all kinds of CPUs. You might be interested in [RMClock](http://cpu.rightmark.org/products/rmclock.shtml). Read the answer from the question I linked in my earlier comment. RMClock is mentioned there.

Comment: @Vinayak - All types of CPUs?  There are two and both are x86 CPUs.  Anything that works on one will work on the other.  The problem is the x86 archecture extension that handles this feature within AMDs and Intel's products are not universal.

Comment: @Ramhound: By different "kinds" of CPUs, what I meant was Intel and AMD processors. And the different processor models (Celeron, Pentium, Core, Athlon, Sempron, etc)

Comment: @Vinayak All those kinds can be controlled through at least one common interface -- ACPI.

Answer (score -1):

You can try making a power plan and setting the maximum processor state:

[image]

Then you can try this answer on superuser to automate switching between profiles quickly: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/957500/easy-way-to-switch-power-plan-in-windows-10)

Comment: You should quote and cite the relevant information from the answer you link to.