# How do I lower processor usage to its bare minimum operating?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, power-consumption

I am running on Windows 7 and I have the habit of not turning off my computer at all. This is due to me hosting some services on my pc that have external users.

The question here is, how do I lower CPU usage and power consumption to its minimum yet keep the services working? Things such as screen rendering should not need to run when i am sleeping or not using the computer. How to I tell the PC to turn off Display on the press of a button? Additionally, what else can I do to lower power consumption?

Comment: As-is, this is too broad (IMO).  How do you know it's not already at it's minimum for your usage?  Have you measured your current power usage?  What steps have you already taken to lower your usage?

Comment: If not for anything the display needs to go. How do i quickly tell the computer to turn off display?

Comment: Perhaps even lower the CPU frequency. I know because after some time where the display turns off, the computer fans stop whiring nosily. I want it to quickly enter that state and not after a unknown duration.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be Power Options

In a Power Plan, you can configure the minimum and maximum state of your CPU, from 0% to 100%. You can also configure your display to turn off when not in use, the shortest time to kick-in being 1 minute.

- [Microsoft answer regarding processor state](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/what-does-the-minimum-processor-state-option-in/74fa379d-c542-e011-9577-d485645a8348?page=1)
- [What Is Minimum And Maximum Processor State In Windows 7 Power Management?](https://superuser.com/a/429326/374398)

However, I personally haven't tested these, I just leave the minimum at 0% and maximum at 100%