# Computer shutdown by bios settings

Tags: windows

I have some case happens with my computer 
When windows is running, then the CPU temperature goes high at the threshold,
Which is responsible for shutting down the computer ?
Is that windows or bios settings ???

Comment: If your computer is shutting down due to the fact it’s overheating, the thermal limits, would be defined within the firmware not Windows.  However, if your machine is overheating, you should NOT increase those limits.  You should address the fact your machine is overheating

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: My comment wasn’t and should not be considered an answer

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes for shutdown:

- The CPU has a thermal sensor for catastrophic shutdown detector which is always
  enabled. When processor core temperature reaches a factory preset level,
  processor execution is halted until reboot.
  The mechanism is builtin to the processor, not under the control of BIOS and
  not dependent on other sensors outside the processor.
- The GPU might have a similar protection sensor.
- Windows surveys all thermal sensors and may decide to do an orderly
  shutdown. It may take action before shutting down, according to
  *Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings > Processor Power Management > Change System Cooling Policy*, where:

  - Active : Increases fan speed before slowing the processor to main cooling,
    for best performance
  - Passive : Slows the processor before increasing fan speed, for quieter fans.

If your computer is overheating you have tried all the usual remedies such as
cleaning, then reducing the CPU maximum performance by a few percents can
do wonders. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/429165/8672).